# sshd banner exchange error messages

Tags: ssh, security

Starting yesterday, began seeing thousands of messages like this in the auth.log

sshd[3635916]: banner exchange: Connection from 202.142.184.68 port 24571: invalid format

Almost 17,000 occurrences of the same ip address shown above, and about 500 occurrences of various other ip addresses.  The ports are always changing, and I wonder if this is a brute force attempt. I have ufw enabled which includes this rule I added several minutes ago

Anywhere                   DENY IN     202.142.184.68

but that hasn't stopped the messages. iplocation places the ip address in Pakistan. I have ssh set up to allow connections from only one port, and it's not the default port for ssh.  For my userid on the server, I ssh (Putty) without a password, using a secure key.

Any way to stop these sshd connection attempts, or whatever they are. Should I try fail2ban as mentioned in [How can I stop ssh bots from trying to SSH in as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913137/how-can-i-stop-ssh-bots-from-trying-to-ssh-in-as-root)?

BTW, server is 22.04.1

Comment: You can try https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/sshguard.8.html also.

Comment: Took a look at the man page.  If I understand correctly, sshguard just automatically updates the firewall based on the logs?  I wonder if sshguard will work, because I updated the firewall via UFW but I'm not seeing 202.142.184.68 being blocked in the ufw log

Comment: sshguard is now running, and I've done the setup with UFW per https://www.tecmint.com/block-ssh-brute-force-attacks-sshguard/.  The "sshd[12973]: banner exchange: Connection from 202.142.184.68 port 13463: invalid format" messages continue, so maybe sshguard and ufw will not stop these attempts, and maybe I should not worry and just consider this an annoyance.  Password auth is set to no, ssh requires a key, and I have 2FA set up

Comment: You can look with  `iptables -S`. Also check `auth.log` for attacks and blocks

Comment: This is in the iptables   sudo iptables -S | grep 202
-A ufw-user-input -s 202.142.184.68/32 -j DROP

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening? Is `banner exchange: Connection from x.x.x.x port 52498: invalid format` indicating someone trying to take advantage of a vulnerability?

Comment: Just found [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66685456/cannot-ssh-my-ubuntu-server-kex-exchange-identification-banner-line-contains) which is useful

Answer (score 0):

My server was getting login attempts about every 40 seconds around the clock.  I use RSA authentication so none of them ever got in but the amount of traffic was bothersome.  I changed the SSH port from 22 to another, unused, port.  Now I get less than one attempt per day.  Some of these attempts consist of requests for banner exchanges which sshd.config is set to refuse.